# Kohana ORM Filters

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am trying to merge two values out of a form into a combined string using filters in Kohana, however I can't work out how to do it / if it is even the best way to do it or not.

I have two values, date and time in a form, which I want to convert to an epoch time string in the model and save that value into a datetime string in the database - what would be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are your best friend in this case. Below you can find example how to use them:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        // Trim all fields
        TRUE => array(
            array('trim'),
        ),
        // Your callback function
        'your_column' => array(
            array(array($this, 'your_callback'))
        ),
    );
}  

public function your_callback($value)
{
    return strtotime($this->date . ' ' . $this->time);
}
```

This filter will set `your_column` to `strtotime($this->date . ' ' . $this->time)` - of course this is just an example. Remember that filters are called before the validation.

**EDIT:**
After thinking through I'd create dedicated method for creating:

```
public function create_($values, $expected)
{
   $values['your_column'] = $values['date'] . ' ' . $values['time'];

   values($values, $expected);

   // Create the object
   return $this->create();
}
```

Of course when you call this method, don't pass `date` and `time` in `$expected` array but `your_column`:

```
ORM::factory('event')->create_($_POST, array('title','venue','your_column', 'guest_count', 'contact_name', 'contact_number','bartab','dj'));
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but I can't work out the controller side of it- I do this:

`$member = ORM::factory('event')->values($_POST, array('title','venue','date','time', 'guest_count', 'contact_name', 'contact_number','bartab','dj'));` and i get an error. i would think it would be passing the values from POST, but disregard column not defined in the model - but it errors out. Clearly I am doing it wrong, but can't work out how best to do it.